# SQL Connection error 40 000webhost with Visual Basic

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am pretty sure I have all of my information right here, but I keep getting this error

http://puu.sh/qoZDQ/7294d6e682.png

The code I used: (Not mine)

I have the right username password and database name (I think)

```
'SET THE CONNECTION BETWEEN VISUAL BASIC AND MYSQL DATABASE
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=mysql9.000webhost.com;" & "Initial Catalog=databasename;" & "User ID=username;" & "Password=password;")

'A SET OF COMMAND IN MYSQL
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
'SET A CLASS THAT SERVES AS THE BRIDGE BETWEEN A DATASET AND DATABASE FOR SAVING AND RETRIEVING DATA.
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
'SET A CLASS THAT CONSISTS SPECIFIC TABLE IN THE DATABASE
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim sqlQuery As String
Dim result As Integer

Private Sub register(ByVal sqlQuery As String)
    Try
        'OPENING THE CONNECTION
        con.Open()
        'HOLDS THE DATA TO BE EXECUTED
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
        End With
        'EXECUTE THE DATA
        Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        'CHECKING IF THE DATA HAS BEEN EXECUTED OR NOT
        If result > 0 Then
            MsgBox("User has been registered.")
        Else
            MsgBox("Failed to register the user.")
        End If
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub login(ByVal sqlQuery As String)
    Try
        con.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
        End With
        'FILLING THE DATA IN A SPECIFIC TABLE OF THE DATABASE
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        'DECLARING AN INTEGER TO SET THE MAXROWS OF THE TABLE
        Dim maxrow As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
        'CHECKING IF THE DATA IS EXIST IN THE ROW OF THE TABLE
        If maxrow > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Welcome " & dt.Rows(0).Item(4))
        Else
            MsgBox("Account does not exist.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Register_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Register.Click
    sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO `dbuser` ( `user_name`, `user_username`, `user_pass`, `user_type`, `user_steamid`)" & "VALUES ('" & txtname.Text & "','" & txtusername.Text & "','" & txtpassword.Text & "','" & cbotype.Text & "','" & txtsteamid.Text & "')"
    register(sqlQuery)
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Login.Click
    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM `dbuser` WHERE user_username ='" & txtusername.Text & "' AND user_pass = '" & txtpassword.Text & "'"
    login(sqlQuery)
End Sub
```

I used the database info from here http://puu.sh/qoZXo/a391cba854.jpg (Also not my info just an example so I dont post my info publicly)

Comment: MySql is not the same thing as Microsoft SqlServer

Comment: So what do I do to fix it?
cause there is not "mysqlclient" for vb that I can find, just SqlClient

Comment: I got the MySQL part fixed downloaded the framework and did "imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient" and now it just says unable to connect... would that be a code issue or server issue?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue with the help of what Plutonix commented

> MySql is not the same thing as Microsoft SqlServer – Plutonix

So I did some googling and found this: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

This is the .Net framework for MySql (I think thats the right terms)

anyhow installing this then changing the top line of my code from

```
imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

To:

```
imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

and changing the sql variables in the code to MySql variables by just adding My to the first bit, and it seems to work "better" I now have a new issue, but its with 000webhosts mysql database, not the code.